# Why does an applet that works fine on one domain not work at another?

Tags: java, php, applet

I developed a voice mailing system and it's working fine at http://mg.gs/vo.

When I transferred the same files to a new domain on the same server — http://VoicePoke.com — the compose page doesn't work. The compose page comprises the Java applet.

Again, it works fine at the first URL but it doesn't respond at the new site. Why?

You can have a look at the compose page by using these login details:
Username: jillz
password: abc

Comment: "the compose page doesn't work" - what does it mean "doesn't work"? Doesn't load? Give exceptions? Doesn't accept mouse input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a 404 not found for http://voicepoke.com/vo/RPApplet.class

Ensure that /vo/RPApplet.class is in the right place on your server and that apache has access to it.

To discover this, I simply loaded the page and inspected requests in firebug's "net" panel.  This is always a good place to start when trying to debug issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here the console reported the missing class, but still loaded the applet.

A little delving into the HTML revealed the archive should be located at..

---

http://voicepoke.com/vo/RPAppletMp3.jar

### Not Found

The requested URL /vo/RPAppletMp3.jar was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at voicepoke.com Port 80